# VBA if statement before executing SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

How can I correctly write an if statement in MS Access VBA that checks if the value in a textbox located on a form is equal to a record in a table column?

The form is called `FormExample` has a textbox called `TextBoxExample`. The table is called `Table1` and the record being updated is `TestTrial` where the `NumberValue` column matches what is in `TextBoxExample`.

If it is equal than execute the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.TestTrial = "Test11"
WHERE (((Table1.NumberValue)=[Forms]![FormExample]![TextBoxExample]));
```

If not display the following message:

```
MsgBox "Sorry" & _
            vbCrLf
```

Comment: Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

To check if the value in the textbox is the same like in the table use a `DCount()` (`DLookup()` would also be possible). I assume, that your textbox value is a `Double` because your value is called `NumberValue`.

```
Dim textboxValue As Double
Dim lookupValue As Double

textboxValue = Me!TextBoxExample.Value
lookupValue = DCount("TestTrial", "Table1", "NumberValue = " & textboxValue)

If Not lookupValue = 0 Then
  Msgbox "One or more records where found."
Else
  Msgbox "No record was found."
End If
```

Comment: I keep getting an error after the DCount saying `The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: " (textboxValue I entered) " `

Comment: Did you use `DCount()` correctly? `=DCount("ColumnName", "TableName", "ColumnValue = 1")`

Comment: I found the issue, is it possible to use a query instead of a table? I appreciate your help